# Creation of java enumeration using xjc in JAXB is not always working correctly

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm creating java classes and enumerations using xjc from the JAXB package from a huge .xsd source. However, xjc is not creating all enums reliable.

Here is just a snippet from this xsd where the creation of a java enumeration is working:

```
    <xs:simpleType name="Dataelement_XY_Z_type">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">

                    <xs:enumeration value="MRI - Unknown" />

                    <xs:enumeration value="MRI - Done, data not available" />

                    <xs:enumeration value="MRI - Done, data available" />

                    <xs:enumeration value="MRI - Not done" />

        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

This snippet is leading to the follwing enum:

```
@XmlType(name = "Dataelement_30_3_type")
@XmlEnum
public enum Dataelement303Type {

    @XmlEnumValue("MRI - Unknown")
    MRI_UNKNOWN("MRI - Unknown"),
    @XmlEnumValue("MRI - Done, data not available")
    MRI_DONE_DATA_NOT_AVAILABLE("MRI - Done, data not available"),
    @XmlEnumValue("MRI - Done, data available")
    MRI_DONE_DATA_AVAILABLE("MRI - Done, data available"),
    @XmlEnumValue("MRI - Not done")
    MRI_NOT_DONE("MRI - Not done");
    private final String value;

    Dataelement303Type(String v) {
        value = v;
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }

    public static Dataelement303Type fromValue(String v) {
        for (Dataelement303Type c: Dataelement303Type.values()) {
            if (c.value.equals(v)) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
    }

}
```

Surpissingly, when I try to create a enum from the follwing code, the creation of the enum fails somehow.

```
<xs:simpleType name="Dataelement_XY_Z_type">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">

                <xs:enumeration value="Signet ring cell carcinoma" />

                <xs:enumeration value="Cribriform comedo-type adenocarcinoma" />

                <xs:enumeration value="Adenocarcinoma" />

                <xs:enumeration value="Mucinous carcinoma" />

                <xs:enumeration value="Signet-ring cell carcinoma" />

                <xs:enumeration value="Medullary carcinoma" />

                <xs:enumeration value="High-grade neuroendocrine carcinoma" />

                <xs:enumeration value="Large cell neuroendocrine carcinoma" />

                <xs:enumeration value="small cell neuroendocrine carcinoma" />

                <xs:enumeration value="Squamous cell carcinoma" />

                <xs:enumeration value="Adeonsquamous carcinoma" />

                <xs:enumeration value="Micropapillary carcinoma" />

                <xs:enumeration value="Serrated adenocarcinoma" />

                <xs:enumeration value="Spindle cell carcinoma" />

                <xs:enumeration value="Mixed adenoneuroendocrine carcinoma" />

                <xs:enumeration value="Undifferentiated carcinoma" />

                <xs:enumeration value="Other" />

    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

But changing the value of the first element in the Dataelement_XZ_Z simply to             `<xs:enumeration value="halloSignet ring cell carcinoma" />` makes the conversion work.

Does anyone has an idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that in your xsd you have:

```
<xs:enumeration value="Signet ring cell carcinoma" />
```

and

```
<xs:enumeration value="Signet-ring cell carcinoma" />
```

Both of which would be turned into "SIGNET_RING_CELL_CARCINOMA" in your enum. This is why it fails. If you comment one of the two, it works.

Comment: Oh hell yes, I didn't see this and unfortunately xjc is not creating an error or warning. Probably when using --verbose.